# Visual Studio debugging visualizer in Visual Studio 2010 Phone Express not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have created a simple Visual Studio debugger which just does not work at all in Visual Studio 2010 Phone Express - it doesn't appear in the list of options. I realise Express editions have limitations but according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb2yca43.aspx), all the Express editions listed support visualisers except the Phone edition is not listed there.

Any suggestions about how to get a debugging visualiser to load in Phone Express?